# Javascript convert array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Google Analytics data:

```
[
["2016-01-01","google","335"],
["2016-01-01","bing","135"],
["2016-01-01","yahoo","35"],
["2016-01-02","google","145"],
["2016-01-02","bing","115"],
...........
]
```

It can be large. What is the simplest and fastest way to get the following two arrays?

An array of the unique date values:

```
["2016-01-01","2016-01-02","2016-01-03","2016-01-04"] - this is uniqe sorting date
```

An array of objects that group the data by source:

```
[{
     source: 'google',
     data: [335, 145,.....] // lenght array=count unique date
}, {
    source: 'bing',
    data: [135, 115,.....]
}, ...
]
```

Comment: are the data sorted?

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to achieve... do you want to extract the dates to one array and the other data to another array with objects (source, data)?

Comment: yes, i can get 2 arrays for visualisation using hightchart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with an intermediate object.

```js
var array = [["2016-01-01", "google", "335"], ["2016-01-01", "bing", "135"], ["2016-01-01", "yahoo", "35"], ["2016-01-02", "google", "145"], ["2016-01-02", "bing", "115"]],
    object = {},
    keys = {},
    uniqueData,
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    keys[a[0]] = true;
    object[a[1]] = object[a[1]] || {};
    object[a[1]][a[0]] = a[2];
});
uniqueData = Object.keys(keys).sort();
grouped = Object.keys(object).map(function (k) {
    return {
        source: k,
        data: uniqueData.map(function (a) {
            return object[k][a] || 0;
        })
    };
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(uniqueData, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

a naive implementation:

```
var arr = [
["2016-01-01","google","335"],
["2016-01-01","bing","135"],
["2016-01-01","yahoo","35"],
["2016-01-02","google","145"],
["2016-01-02","bing","115"],
];

var new_arr = [];
var sources = {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if ( sources[arr[i][1]] ){
        sources[arr[i][1]].data.push(arr[i][2])
    } else {
      sources[arr[i][1]] = {
        source: arr[i][1],
        data: [ arr[i][2] ],
      }
    }
}

for (var key in sources) {
   if (sources.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      new_arr.push(sources[key]);
   }
}

console.log(new_arr);
```

The code above gets you the second array. 
The first array should be much simpler to obtain and would be a good exercise for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedUniq), then it is pretty simple:

```js
var data = [
  ["2016-01-01","google","335"],
  ["2016-01-01","bing","135"],
  ["2016-01-01","yahoo","35"],
  ["2016-01-02","google","145"],
  ["2016-01-02","bing","115"]
];

var first = _.sortedUniq(data.map(x => x[0]).sort());
var second = _.entries(_.groupBy(data, x => x[1])).map(
    e => ({ source: e[0], data: e[1].map(d => d[2]) }) );

logs.innerText = JSON.stringify(first, null, 2) + "\n" + JSON.stringify(second, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="logs"></pre>
```